# Black screen in Guix System installation

Tags: iso, gnu, signature, guix, guixsd

I have this problem to install Guix System:

[image]

After this, the screen turns black and nothing is displayed.

I first downloaded the Guix System, extracted the iso with this command: "unxz" and then burned it to a 4.7GB DVD-R with "Brasero".

graphics card: NVIDIA GT720

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to install the system by putting "nomodeset" in grub.

[image: Screenshot of the grub screen]

Follow the continuation here: https://issues.guix.gnu.org/44301