# Black screen during OS installation

Tags: debian, arch-linux, system-installation, live-usb

I have a problem where I can get into the EFI boot loader screen of a distro but I cannot enter into the live iso. No matter whether I select "boot with open source drivers", "boot with proprietary drivers", "no nouveau", "nomodeset" or any of the options each distro provides. So, far I have the following distros with the latest iso available at the time of writing exhibit this particular problem: KaOS, Manjaro, Garuda, PopOS.

EndeavorOS, and Fedora won't even load the boot loader and just turns off the screen. (The device remains on but the monitor loses signal)

Ubuntu, KDE Neon, and Linux Lite only boot up in safe mode but not in the default mode.

The installation media has been created using Ventoy and has been verified to work on other devices.

Hardware Specs:

- CPU: i5 2600 2nd Gen
- Motherboard: Biostar h61MH
- GPU: Processor IGPU
- RAM: 2x8GB DDR3

Bios Settings:

- UEFI Boot enabled
- VTx on
- Virtualization on

I have tried the method [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/616850/black-screen-in-guix-system-installation) but to no avail.

I would greatly appreciate a way to boot into these distros so I may install them, preferably an Arch-based one.

Comment: Please try Fedora 35 beta which contains the most recent kernel 5.14. `nomodeset` should have helped btw. Are you sure it doesn't work?

Comment: I will but since the hardware is quite old, shouldn't I be looking at distros with LTS kernels? I added `nomodeset` to the params that appear then I press the `e` key on keyboard during the boot process. Is this not the correct way?